# Media players on users feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

When publishing to the users Feed how are applications like YouTube and Soundcloud able to have a media player load within their feed post on the users wall?

Answer (score 0):

You just specify the type in the head of your page by adding meta tags with the correct og types and data.

> If you want to attach a video to your Open Graph page you can simply specify a video url:
>
> og:video - e.g., "http://example.com/awesome.swf"
>
> In a similar fashion to og:video you can add an audio file to your
> markup:
>
> og:audio - e.g., "http://example.com/amazing.mp3"

See the following url for more details (under Attaching Audio and Video Data):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Then when people link to your page or like your content, it will appear just like youtube/soundcloud with the player in the news stream.